# Replace data in one colums of a range

Tags: excel, vba

I have filtered a workbook and I need to replace all the data in Column A with "ISSUE".  This appears to be simple enough and I sure it is as I can get it to work no problem when I have no filter on.

I have setup a dynamic range and used 'For each cell in DRange' but no joy.

Any suggestions or help would be greatly appreciated,

Thanks,

Ciaran

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do the following:

1. Apply filter as you wish.
2. Select all the values in `A` you need to replace.
3. Having selection applied, type "ISSUE", but press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd> instead of usual <kbd>ENTER</kbd> - this will autofill the whole selected range with typed value, and only FILTERED values.

Comment: Thanks Peter (as always).  I can do it in excel.  But when I try it in VB I can't seem to skip though Columns A as it populates "Issue" for everything in column A (not just what I filtered.

Comment: 2 wild guesses: 1) Consider to use `Selection` range as soon as filter is applied - not sure and dirty one... 2) Instead of filtering - loop through rows and check for the same conditions you apply filter, and then replace values in `A` depending the result. Get back if neither was helpful)

Comment: I think Selection is the option to use (dirty as you said) but should do the trick.  Thanks Peter.

Comment: Instead of `Selection` you could also use `Range(...).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)` - less dirty! ;-)

Comment: @PeterAlbert nice catch Peter, didn't know about that!